# React Native broken engine - Invariant Violation

Tags: ios, reactjs, iphone, react-native

```
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: `new NativeEventEmitter()` requires a non-null argument., js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 10): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient.
        A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 10): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient.
        A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes
```

The biggest problem is that I don't know what I did wrong. I tried to install [React Native WebView](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-webview) to integrate Google reCAPTCHA-a, `pod install` and boom, engine is broken.

I have tried to remove `Podfile.lock`, `Pods` folder itself, Clean build from xCode, but not working.

```
{
  "name": "....",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.11",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.8",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.10",
    "axios": "^1.3.3",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.7",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.6",
    "react-native-config": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-inappbrowser-reborn": "^3.7.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.14.4",
    "react-native-reanimated-carousel": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.20.0",
    "react-native-skeleton-placeholder": "^5.2.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.26.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.70.6",
    "@types/react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.13",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.37.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.37.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.72.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

Restart my laptop, clear `node_modules` install them again, but not working...

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import {WebView} from 'react-native-webview';

interface ContactFormProps {
  onSubmit: (formData: FormData) => void;
}

const ContactForm: React.FC<ContactFormProps> = ({onSubmit}) => {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [topic, setTopic] = useState('');
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const [captchaToken, setCaptchaToken] = useState('');

  const RECAPTCHA_KEY = '.......';

  const handleFormSubmit = () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('firstName', firstName);
    formData.append('lastName', lastName);
    formData.append('email', email);
    formData.append('topic', topic);
    formData.append('message', message);
    formData.append('captchaToken', captchaToken);
    onSubmit(formData);
  };

  const handleCaptchaToken = (token: string) => {
    setCaptchaToken(token);
  };

  const handleWebViewMessage = (event: any) => {
    if (event.nativeEvent.data.startsWith('token:')) {
      const token = event.nativeEvent.data.replace('token:', '');
      handleCaptchaToken(token);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>First Name</Text>
      <TextInput value={firstName} onChangeText={setFirstName} />
      <Text>Last Name</Text>
      <TextInput value={lastName} onChangeText={setLastName} />
      <Text>Email</Text>
      <TextInput value={email} onChangeText={setEmail} />
      <Text>Topic</Text>
      <TextInput value={topic} onChangeText={setTopic} />
      <Text>Message</Text>
      <TextInput value={message} onChangeText={setMessage} />
      <WebView
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        source={{html: '<h1>Hello world</h1>'}}
      />
      <WebView
        source={{
          uri: `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&k=${RECAPTCHA_KEY}&co=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cueW91dHViZS5jb206NDQz&hl=en&v=OLaQV-m_bCAfHtZ1zjZc5F9S&size=normal&cb=abcdefg123456`,
        }}
        onMessage={handleWebViewMessage}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        thirdPartyCookiesEnabled={true}
      />
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleFormSubmit}>
        <Text>Submit</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default ContactForm;
```

Runs `pod install & pod update`... Nothing helped...